# Why does my vector size keep resetting to 0? (currently using classes)

Tags: c++, vector

I've been trying to make a polynomial class, and I've got almost half of it done. However, my vectors keep resetting to 0 after "polynomial q(coeff, expo);", can anyone tell me why?

```
class polynomial {
  public:
    polynomial();
    polynomial(vector<float> coefficient, vector<int> degree);

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const polynomial& y);

  private:
    vector<float> coeff1;
    vector<int> expo1;
};

polynomial::polynomial(){
  coeff1.clear();
  expo1.clear();
  coeff1.push_back(1);
}

polynomial::polynomial(vector<float> coefficient, vector<int> degree){
  if (coefficient.size() != degree.size()){
    cout << "Error. The number of coefficients are not the same as the number of exponents. Polynomial will be set to 1." << endl;
    polynomial();
  }
  else {

    for (int b = 0; b<degree.size(); b++) {
      for (int c = 0; c<b; c++){
        if (degree[b] > degree[c]){
          int holder = degree[b];
          degree[b] = degree[c];
          degree[c] = holder;

          float holder1 = coefficient[b];
          coefficient[b] = coefficient[c];
          coefficient[c] = holder1;
        }
      }
    }


    for (int a = 0; a<coefficient.size(); a++) {
      coeff1.push_back (coefficient[a]);
      expo1.push_back (degree[a]);
    }
  }
}


ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const polynomial& y){
  if (y.coeff1.size() != y.expo1.size()) {
    os << 1;
    return os;
  }
  else {
    for (int x = 0; x<y.coeff1.size(); x++){
      if (y.coeff1[x] != y.coeff1[y.coeff1.size() - 1]) {
        if (y.expo1[x] == 1){
          os << y.coeff1[x] << "x" << " + ";
        }
        else if(y.expo1[x] == 0) {
          os << y.coeff1[x];
        }
        else {
          os << y.coeff1[x] << "x^" << y.expo1[x] << " + ";
        }
      }
      else {
        if (y.expo1[x] == 1){
          os << y.coeff1[x] << "x";
        }
        else if(y.expo1[x] == 0) {
          os << y.coeff1[x];
        }
      }

    }

    return os;
  }
}

int main()
{
  vector<float> coeff;
  vector<int> expo;

  coeff.push_back(3);
  coeff.push_back(16);
  coeff.push_back(10);
  //    coeff.push_back(7);

  expo.push_back(4);
  expo.push_back(1);
  expo.push_back(2);
  expo.push_back(3);


  polynomial p;
  cout << "The polynomial is: " << p << endl;
  polynomial q(coeff, expo);
  cout << "The polynomial is: " << q << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

[there are useless lines of code because i wanted to check where the size of my vector was changing to 0]

Comment: Why the `new int`?   And your copy constructor is totally wrong, which is probably why you're having problems.  You're making partial / bogus copies since you didn't copy the vectors.  If you got rid of that `new int` stuff, you don't need a copy constructor.

Comment: Yeah, I know, as I said some parts are still pretty useless. And, the vector still becomes 0 even if I did remove the copy constructor. :/ I'm really just asking why the size keeps turning into 0. Don't mind the other parts because I'm pretty sure they're not affecting the vectors that I'm using.

Comment: @tupsman When asking questions, please reduce your question to the minimal amount of code that can demonstrate a specific problem that you have.  See what the help section says about a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  (That would mean in this case no definitions for operators you don't use, for starters)  Note the *edit* button.

Comment: `polynomial();` This creates a temporary object and then immediately discards it.

Comment: It's weird because the size does become 1 and 0 during "q(coeff,expo)", but then once I get to the ostream operator, it becomes 0 and 0. Really weird, right? Ugh. I'm starting to think that maybe it has something to do with the constructors? Because from what I know, constructors are supposed to automatically execute once the class is used.

Comment: @HostileFork My apologies, haha. I'll do that if ever I need to ask anything else. :D

Comment: @Neil Kirk So is there a way of making the change permanent..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
polynomial();
```

creates an unnamed object and immediately destroys it. It has the same effect as:

```
{
    polynomial x;
}
```

I guess you were trying to "call the constructor".  However this is not possible, constructors are special and can only be 'called' by virtue of the attempt to create an object; or from the ctor-initializer list .

---

I would suggest redesigning your constructors. Firstly, the copy-constructor is bogus (it doesn't copy any of the fields except `ptr`, and also `int *ptr` was not initialized by the normal constructors). In fact `int *ptr;` should be removed entirely.

In the constructor `polynomial()` , the calls to `clear()` are redundant. Vectors start off empty, and since this is a constructor, it's only called on a polynomial that is just in the business of being created for the first time.

I would suggest doing this for the constructor taking two arguments:

```
polynomial::polynomial(vector<float> coefficient, vector<int> degree)
{
    if (coefficient.size() != degree.size())
    {
    // typically it would be better to just throw an exception here, the caller will not expect a 1-polynomial 
        std::cerr << "Error. The number of coefficients are not the same as the number of exponents. Polynomial will be set to 1." << std::endl;
        coeff1.push_back(1);
        wala();
    }
    else 
    {
        set_polynomial(coefficient, degree);
    }
}
```

and move your other logic for sorting the coefficient and degree into a private function called `set_polynomial`. This keeps your constructor easy to read and your code tidy; you may want to use this function at a later time to allow the user to change a polynomial.

Pro tip: look into `std::tie`, you can actually sort `coefficient` and `degree` together using a single command.

Comment: Alright, I guess I should just put the contents of the constructor in there instead of calling "polynomial()". Thanks!

Edit: It worked! Hahaha i love the people on this site

Comment: @tupsman yep, since it is so simple then that is a good solution. If the code were more complicated then one approach would be to make that code be in another function, which you call from both your constructors.

Comment: Actually I will update the suggestion I've just posted, in a few minutes